# Cannot resolve symbol, editText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I always getting error, with any code, where you have to use your editText, no matter, that i'm writing the correct edit text ID, the Android Studio not recognize my editText. I try to check that my editText field is empty, and if it's empty, turn my START button INVISIBLE, if it's not empty, than turn it to VISIBLE.
But no matter what i'm doing, i'm getting red color to editText. I tried to paste it to on create, after on create, but nothing happens, what am I doing wrong?

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString())
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "plz enter your name ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
```

No matter what example am I trying, I'm always get error to getText, or to editText. Maybe somehow at the top of my activity, I have to define them? Or what? Help me please.

I tried this code too, but nothing happens, when I run my app, but the good thing, it's not giving me error for editText

Here's a another example, that also not works.

```
private boolean isEmpty(EditText editText) {
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        if (editText.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0)
        {
            editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        } else {
            editText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you changing the visibility of your editText? You want to change the visibility of the START button. So, apply it on button instead of editText.

Comment: Yeah, actually I changed it now to button.setVisibility but nothing happens.

Comment: Add this in the top of your activity `import android.widget.EditText;`

Comment: Can you please state the exact error you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a String parameter in your function named isEmpty(String) and your method demands an EditText parameter isEmpty(EditText). The signatures of your method call doesn't resembles with the actual method because of which you are getting the error.

try this

```
isEmpty(editText)
```

instead of

```
isEmpty(editText.getText().toString())
```